# Issue when creating phonegap build

Tags: android, phonegap-build

I am trying to create build using https://build.phonegap.com/. I want to open pdf from external link and I get this error. Please help me to figure out this.

> Error - A plugin you are using requires a preference:
>   ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION

myconfig.xml file:

Casper

```
<author email="test@gmail.com" href="http://www.test.com/">
    Test Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
<allow-intent href="cdvfile://*" />
<access origin="file://*" />
<allow-intent href="file://*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
<external-path name="external_files" path="." />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" source="npm" spec="^2.2.1"/>
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" source="npm" spec="^1.5.6" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <splash src="splash.png" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
</platform>
```